# for each loop through a case statement

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have this code and I'm trying to remove rows where case 0 - 7 are all zero's.  Is it better to do a for loop, or use if-then?:

```
tmpEditRow.BeginEdit()

            Select Case a
                Case 0
                    tmpEditRow("Qsold / QoH1") = QtySold & " / " & QtyOH
                Case 1
                    tmpEditRow("Qsold / QoH3") = QtySold & " / " & QtyOH
                Case 2
                    tmpEditRow("Qsold / QoH4") = QtySold & " / " & QtyOH
                Case 3
                    tmpEditRow("Qsold / QoH7") = QtySold & " / " & QtyOH
                Case 4
                    tmpEditRow("Qsold / QoH8") = QtySold & " / " & QtyOH
                Case 5
                    tmpEditRow("Qsold / QoH10") = QtySold & " / " & QtyOH
                Case 6
                    tmpEditRow("Qsold / QoH12") = QtySold & " / " & QtyOH
                Case 7
                    tmpEditRow("Qsold / QoH14") = QtySold & " / " & QtyOH
             End Select
                    tmpEditRow.EndEdit()
```

Comment: Could you explain the use case? What do you try to achieve?

Comment: I think he wants to know if using a switch statement or an if/else block is the better approach to determine is an operation should be performed.

Comment: it's actually a polling applicaton that determines if an item has sold / and the quantity on hand.  my results are producing all items and whether or not they sold and what the qty oh is to prevent having to re-poll each location over and over.  if it didn't sell any where and qoh is zero i don't want it in the data grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use a variable for doing the calculation and then check for a 0 value

**Update:** If QtyOH is the current value for each case `a` then it gets even more simplified:

```
If QtyOH <> 0 Then
    tmpEditRow.BeginEdit()

    Dim bucket as String = ""
    Select Case a
        Case 0
            bucket = "1"
        Case 1
            bucket = "3"
        Case 2
            bucket = "4"
        .
        .
        .
    End Select

    tmpEditRow("Qsold / QoH" & bucket) = QtySold & " / " & QtyOH
    tmpEditRow.EndEdit()
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Select Case` is okay. However it is my preference to organize code such that the actual computation can be consolidated within a singular block whenever possible (unless performance/optimization/resource issues require otherwise), for read-ability and maintenance.

```
tmpEditRow.BeginEdit()

' Note: Assuming variables [QtySold] and [QtyOH] are numeric
' values, each set appropriately for whatever variable
' [a] is meant to indicate.

' [ColKey] is the column of interest within [tmpEditRow], as
' appropriate per [a].
Dim ColKey As String = Nothing
Select Case a
    Case 0: ColKey = "Qsold / QoH1"
    Case 1: ColKey = "Qsold / QoH3"
    Case 2: ColKey = "Qsold / QoH4"
    Case 3: ColKey = "Qsold / QoH7"
    Case 4: ColKey = "Qsold / QoH8"
    Case 5: ColKey = "Qsold / QoH10"
    Case 6: ColKey = "Qsold / QoH12"
    Case 7: ColKey = "Qsold / QoH14"
End Select

' The actual computation, right here, via [ColValue].
' [ColValue] is the text to place at [ColKey] of [tmpEditRow].
Dim ColValue As String = Nothing
If QtyOH = 0 Then
    ColValue = ""
Else
    ColValue = QtySold & " / " & QtyOH
End If    
tmpEditRow(ColKey) = ColValue

tmpEditRow.EndEdit()
```

Answer (score -1):

You could condense this into something like

```
if ( a == 0 )
    tmpEditRow("Qsold / QoH1") = QtySold & " / " & QtyOH
else if ( a == 1 )
    tmpEditRow("Qsold / QoH3") = QtySold & " / " & QtyOH    
else if ( a == 3 )
    tmpEditRow("Qsold / QoH7") = QtySold & " / " & QtyOH
else if (a == "2|[5-7]") //regex comparison
    tmpEditRow("Qsold / QoH" + (a*2) ) = QtySold & " / " & QtyOH
else
    tmpEditRow.EndEdit()
```

**Edit**

I just noticed the "QoH_" part isn't created by multiplying a times two. In any case, you could still do this with an if/else block.

Comment: What a strange dialect of vb.net